# How to compute a cumulative sum under a limit with Spark?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

After several tries and some research, I'm stuck on trying to solve the following problem with Spark.

I have a Dataframe of elements with a priority and a quantity.

```
+------+-------+--------+---+
|family|element|priority|qty|
+------+-------+--------+---+
|    f1| elmt 1|       1| 20|
|    f1| elmt 2|       2| 40|
|    f1| elmt 3|       3| 10|
|    f1| elmt 4|       4| 50|
|    f1| elmt 5|       5| 40|
|    f1| elmt 6|       6| 10|
|    f1| elmt 7|       7| 20|
|    f1| elmt 8|       8| 10|
+------+-------+--------+---+
```

I have a fixed limit quantity :

```
+------+--------+
|family|limitQty|
+------+--------+
|    f1|     100|
+------+--------+
```

I want to mark as "ok" the elements whose the cumulative sum is under the limit. Here is the expected result :

```
+------+-------+--------+---+---+
|family|element|priority|qty| ok|
+------+-------+--------+---+---+
|    f1| elmt 1|       1| 20|  1| -> 20 < 100   => ok
|    f1| elmt 2|       2| 40|  1| -> 20 + 40 < 100  => ok
|    f1| elmt 3|       3| 10|  1| -> 20 + 40 + 10 < 100   => ok
|    f1| elmt 4|       4| 50|  0| -> 20 + 40 + 10 + 50 > 100   => ko 
|    f1| elmt 5|       5| 40|  0| -> 20 + 40 + 10 + 40 > 100   => ko  
|    f1| elmt 6|       6| 10|  1| -> 20 + 40 + 10 + 10 < 100   => ok
|    f1| elmt 7|       7| 20|  1| -> 20 + 40 + 10 + 10 + 20 < 100   => ok
|    f1| elmt 8|       8| 10|  0| -> 20 + 40 + 10 + 10 + 20 + 10 > 100   => ko
+------+-------+--------+---+---+
```

I try to solve if with a cumulative sum :

```scala
    initDF
      .join(limitQtyDF, Seq("family"), "left_outer")
      .withColumn("cumulSum", sum($"qty").over(Window.partitionBy("family").orderBy("priority")))
      .withColumn("ok", when($"cumulSum" <= $"limitQty", 1).otherwise(0))
      .drop("cumulSum", "limitQty")
```

But it's not enough because the elements after the element that is up to the limit are not take into account. 
I can't find a way to solve it with Spark. Do you have an idea ?

Here is the corresponding Scala code :

```scala
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val initDF = Seq(
      ("f1", "elmt 1", 1, 20),
      ("f1", "elmt 2", 2, 40),
      ("f1", "elmt 3", 3, 10),
      ("f1", "elmt 4", 4, 50),
      ("f1", "elmt 5", 5, 40),
      ("f1", "elmt 6", 6, 10),
      ("f1", "elmt 7", 7, 20),
      ("f1", "elmt 8", 8, 10)
    ).toDF("family", "element", "priority", "qty")

    val limitQtyDF = Seq(("f1", 100)).toDF("family", "limitQty")

    val expectedDF = Seq(
      ("f1", "elmt 1", 1, 20, 1),
      ("f1", "elmt 2", 2, 40, 1),
      ("f1", "elmt 3", 3, 10, 1),
      ("f1", "elmt 4", 4, 50, 0),
      ("f1", "elmt 5", 5, 40, 0),
      ("f1", "elmt 6", 6, 10, 1),
      ("f1", "elmt 7", 7, 20, 1),
      ("f1", "elmt 8", 8, 10, 0)
    ).toDF("family", "element", "priority", "qty", "ok").show()
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You need some kind of recursion to do that, windowing is not enough. Do you want a scala solution only, or is SQL an option?

Comment: I want a Spark solution, so a pure SQL solution can help and be transposed to Spark SQL. I take a look on recursion possibilities with Spark.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is shown below:

```
scala> initDF.show
+------+-------+--------+---+
|family|element|priority|qty|
+------+-------+--------+---+
|    f1| elmt 1|       1| 20|
|    f1| elmt 2|       2| 40|
|    f1| elmt 3|       3| 10|
|    f1| elmt 4|       4| 50|
|    f1| elmt 5|       5| 40|
|    f1| elmt 6|       6| 10|
|    f1| elmt 7|       7| 20|
|    f1| elmt 8|       8| 10|
+------+-------+--------+---+

scala> val df1 = initDF.groupBy("family").agg(collect_list("qty").as("comb_qty"), collect_list("priority").as("comb_prior"), collect_list("element").as("comb_elem"))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [family: string, comb_qty: array<int> ... 2 more fields]

scala> df1.show
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|family|            comb_qty|          comb_prior|           comb_elem|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    f1|[20, 40, 10, 50, ...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...|[elmt 1, elmt 2, ...|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+


scala> val df2 = df1.join(limitQtyDF, df1("family") === limitQtyDF("family")).drop(limitQtyDF("family"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [family: string, comb_qty: array<int> ... 3 more fields]

scala> df2.show
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|family|            comb_qty|          comb_prior|           comb_elem|limitQty|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|    f1|[20, 40, 10, 50, ...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...|[elmt 1, elmt 2, ...|     100|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+


scala> def validCheck = (qty: Seq[Int], limit: Int) => {
     | var sum = 0
     | qty.map(elem => {
     | if (elem + sum <= limit) {
     | sum = sum + elem
     | 1}else{
     | 0
     | }})}
validCheck: (scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int], Int) => scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]

scala> val newUdf = udf(validCheck)
newUdf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,ArrayType(IntegerType,false),Some(List(ArrayType(IntegerType,false), IntegerType)))

val df3 = df2.withColumn("valid", newUdf(col("comb_qty"),col("limitQty"))).drop("limitQty")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [family: string, comb_qty: array<int> ... 3 more fields]

scala> df3.show
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|family|            comb_qty|          comb_prior|           comb_elem|               valid|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    f1|[20, 40, 10, 50, ...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...|[elmt 1, elmt 2, ...|[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1...|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+

scala> val myUdf = udf((qty: Seq[Int], prior: Seq[Int], elem: Seq[String], valid: Seq[Int]) => {
     | elem zip prior zip qty zip valid map{
     | case (((a,b),c),d) => (a,b,c,d)}
     | }
     | )

scala> val df4 = df3.withColumn("combined", myUdf(col("comb_qty"),col("comb_prior"),col("comb_elem"),col("valid")))
df4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [family: string, comb_qty: array<int> ... 4 more fields]



scala> val df5 = df4.drop("comb_qty","comb_prior","comb_elem","valid")
df5: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [family: string, combined: array<struct<_1:string,_2:int,_3:int,_4:int>>]

scala> df5.show(false)
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|family|combined                                                                                                                                                        |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|f1    |[[elmt 1, 1, 20, 1], [elmt 2, 2, 40, 1], [elmt 3, 3, 10, 1], [elmt 4, 4, 50, 0], [elmt 5, 5, 40, 0], [elmt 6, 6, 10, 1], [elmt 7, 7, 20, 1], [elmt 8, 8, 10, 0]]|
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

scala> val df6 = df5.withColumn("combined",explode(col("combined")))
df6: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [family: string, combined: struct<_1: string, _2: int ... 2 more fields>]

scala> df6.show
+------+------------------+
|family|          combined|
+------+------------------+
|    f1|[elmt 1, 1, 20, 1]|
|    f1|[elmt 2, 2, 40, 1]|
|    f1|[elmt 3, 3, 10, 1]|
|    f1|[elmt 4, 4, 50, 0]|
|    f1|[elmt 5, 5, 40, 0]|
|    f1|[elmt 6, 6, 10, 1]|
|    f1|[elmt 7, 7, 20, 1]|
|    f1|[elmt 8, 8, 10, 0]|
+------+------------------+

scala> val df7 = df6.select("family", "combined._1", "combined._2", "combined._3", "combined._4").withColumnRenamed("_1","element").withColumnRenamed("_2","priority").withColumnRenamed("_3", "qty").withColumnRenamed("_4","ok")
df7: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [family: string, element: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> df7.show
+------+-------+--------+---+---+
|family|element|priority|qty| ok|
+------+-------+--------+---+---+
|    f1| elmt 1|       1| 20|  1|
|    f1| elmt 2|       2| 40|  1|
|    f1| elmt 3|       3| 10|  1|
|    f1| elmt 4|       4| 50|  0|
|    f1| elmt 5|       5| 40|  0|
|    f1| elmt 6|       6| 10|  1|
|    f1| elmt 7|       7| 20|  1|
|    f1| elmt 8|       8| 10|  0|
+------+-------+--------+---+---+
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Your solution solve the problem ! But I have two questions on it. I see that there is an implicit order between arrays (comb_qty, comb_prior, comb_elem), ie index 0 in arrays is for the element 0. Does Spark guarantees the order ? And a question about scalability, if I have 10k element by family, is this solution is still viable ? Thanks for your solution !

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it will be an RDD based approach by iterating row by row.

```
var bufferRow: collection.mutable.Buffer[Row] = collection.mutable.Buffer.empty[Row]
var tempSum: Double = 0
val iterator = df.collect.iterator
while(iterator.hasNext){
  val record = iterator.next()
  val y = record.getAs[Integer]("qty")
  tempSum = tempSum + y
  print(record)
  if (tempSum <= 100.0 ) {
    bufferRow = bufferRow ++ Seq(transformRow(record,1))
  }
  else{
    bufferRow = bufferRow ++ Seq(transformRow(record,0))
    tempSum = tempSum - y
  }
}
```

Defining `transformRow` function which is used to add a column to a row.

```
def transformRow(row: Row,flag : Int): Row =  Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array[Integer](flag))
```

Next thing to do will be adding an additional column to the schema.

```
val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("C_Sum", IntegerType, false))
```

Followed by creating a new dataframe.

```
val outputdf = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(bufferRow.toSeq),newSchema)
```

Output Dataframe :

```
+------+-------+--------+---+-----+
|family|element|priority|qty|C_Sum|
+------+-------+--------+---+-----+
|    f1|  elmt1|       1| 20|    1|
|    f1|  elmt2|       2| 40|    1|
|    f1|  elmt3|       3| 10|    1|
|    f1|  elmt4|       4| 50|    0|
|    f1|  elmt5|       5| 40|    0|
|    f1|  elmt6|       6| 10|    1|
|    f1|  elmt7|       7| 20|    1|
|    f1|  elmt8|       8| 10|    0|
+------+-------+--------+---+-----+
```

Comment: As jrook solution, I can't collect data on master because of the number of rows (> 10 millions). But your idea to work with RDD rather than Dataframe can be a good idea. Thank you !

Comment: I get your point, will look into it, do let us know your solution will be interesting definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Spark so this solution may not be optimal. I am assuming the value of 100 is an input to the program here. In that case:

```
case class Frame(family:String, element : String, priority : Int, qty :Int)

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val ans = df.as[Frame].toLocalIterator
  .asScala
  .foldLeft((Seq.empty[Int],0))((acc,a) => 
    if(acc._2 + a.qty <= 100) (acc._1 :+ a.priority, acc._2 + a.qty) else acc)._1

df.withColumn("OK" , when($"priority".isin(ans :_*), 1).otherwise(0)).show
```

results in:

```
+------+-------+--------+---+--------+
|family|element|priority|qty|OK      |
+------+-------+--------+---+--------+
|    f1| elmt 1|       1| 20|       1|
|    f1| elmt 2|       2| 40|       1|
|    f1| elmt 3|       3| 10|       1|
|    f1| elmt 4|       4| 50|       0|
|    f1| elmt 5|       5| 40|       0|
|    f1| elmt 6|       6| 10|       1|
|    f1| elmt 7|       7| 20|       1|
|    f1| elmt 8|       8| 10|       0|
+------+-------+--------+---+--------+
```

The idea is simply to get a Scala iterator and extract the participating `priority` values from it and then use those values to filter out the participating rows. Given this solution gathers all the data in memory on one machine, it could run into memory problems if the dataframe size is too large to fit in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but unfortunately I can't collect data because the DataFrame has sevaral millions of rows :/

Answer (score 0):

Cumulative sum for each group

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as window
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,StringType,FloatType,StructType,StructField,DateType
schema = StructType() \
        .add(StructField("empno",IntegerType(),True)) \
        .add(StructField("ename",StringType(),True)) \
        .add(StructField("job",StringType(),True)) \
        .add(StructField("mgr",StringType(),True)) \
        .add(StructField("hiredate",DateType(),True)) \
        .add(StructField("sal",FloatType(),True)) \
        .add(StructField("comm",StringType(),True)) \
        .add(StructField("deptno",IntegerType(),True))

emp = spark.read.csv('data/emp.csv',schema)
dept_partition = window.partitionBy(emp.deptno).orderBy(emp.sal)
emp_win = emp.withColumn("dept_cum_sal", 
                         f.sum(emp.sal).over(dept_partition.rowsBetween(window.unboundedPreceding, window.currentRow)))
emp_win.show()
```

Results appear like below:

```
+-----+------+---------+----+----------+------+-------+------+------------ 
+
|empno| ename|      job| mgr|  hiredate|   sal|   comm|deptno|dept_cum_sal|
+-----+------+---------+----+----------+------+-------+------+------------ 
+
| 7369| SMITH|    CLERK|7902|1980-12-17| 800.0|   null|    20|       800.0|
| 7876| ADAMS|    CLERK|7788|1983-01-12|1100.0|   null|    20|      1900.0|
| 7566| JONES|  MANAGER|7839|1981-04-02|2975.0|   null|    20|      4875.0|
| 7788| SCOTT|  ANALYST|7566|1982-12-09|3000.0|   null|    20|      7875.0|
| 7902|  FORD|  ANALYST|7566|1981-12-03|3000.0|   null|    20|     10875.0|
| 7934|MILLER|    CLERK|7782|1982-01-23|1300.0|   null|    10|      1300.0|
| 7782| CLARK|  MANAGER|7839|1981-06-09|2450.0|   null|    10|      3750.0|
| 7839|  KING|PRESIDENT|null|1981-11-17|5000.0|   null|    10|      8750.0|
| 7900| JAMES|    CLERK|7698|1981-12-03| 950.0|   null|    30|       950.0|
| 7521|  WARD| SALESMAN|7698|1981-02-22|1250.0| 500.00|    30|      2200.0|
| 7654|MARTIN| SALESMAN|7698|1981-09-28|1250.0|1400.00|    30|      3450.0|
| 7844|TURNER| SALESMAN|7698|1981-09-08|1500.0|   0.00|    30|      4950.0|
| 7499| ALLEN| SALESMAN|7698|1981-02-20|1600.0| 300.00|    30|      6550.0|
| 7698| BLAKE|  MANAGER|7839|1981-05-01|2850.0|   null|    30|      9400.0|
+-----+------+---------+----+----------+------+-------+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

PFA the answer

```
val initDF = Seq(("f1", "elmt 1", 1, 20),("f1", "elmt 2", 2, 40),("f1", "elmt 3", 3, 10),
      ("f1", "elmt 4", 4, 50),
      ("f1", "elmt 5", 5, 40),
      ("f1", "elmt 6", 6, 10),
      ("f1", "elmt 7", 7, 20),
      ("f1", "elmt 8", 8, 10)
    ).toDF("family", "element", "priority", "qty")

val limitQtyDF = Seq(("f1", 100)).toDF("family", "limitQty")

sc.broadcast(limitQtyDF)


val joinedInitDF=initDF.join(limitQtyDF,Seq("family"),"left")

case class dataResult(family:String,element:String,priority:Int, qty:Int, comutedValue:Int, limitQty:Int,controlOut:String) 
val familyIDs=initDF.select("family").distinct.collect.map(_(0).toString).toList

def checkingUDF(inputRows:List[Row])={
var controlVarQty=0
val outputArrayBuffer=collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[dataResult]()
val setLimit=inputRows.head.getInt(4) 
for(inputRow <- inputRows)
{
val currQty=inputRow.getInt(3) 
//val outpurForRec=
controlVarQty + currQty match {
case value if value <= setLimit => 
controlVarQty+=currQty
outputArrayBuffer+=dataResult(inputRow.getString(0),inputRow.getString(1),inputRow.getInt(2),inputRow.getInt(3),value,setLimit,"ok")
case value => 
outputArrayBuffer+=dataResult(inputRow.getString(0),inputRow.getString(1),inputRow.getInt(2),inputRow.getInt(3),value,setLimit,"ko")
}
//outputArrayBuffer+=Row(inputRow.getString(0),inputRow.getString(1),inputRow.getInt(2),inputRow.getInt(3),controlVarQty+currQty,setLimit,outpurForRec)
}
outputArrayBuffer.toList
}

val tmpAB=collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[List[dataResult]]()
for (familyID <- familyIDs) // val familyID="f1"
{
val currentFamily=joinedInitDF.filter(s"family = '${familyID}'").orderBy("element", "priority").collect.toList
tmpAB+=checkingUDF(currentFamily)
}

tmpAB.toSeq.flatMap(x => x).toDF.show(false)
```

This works for me .

```
+------+-------+--------+---+------------+--------+----------+
|family|element|priority|qty|comutedValue|limitQty|controlOut|
+------+-------+--------+---+------------+--------+----------+
|f1    |elmt 1 |1       |20 |20          |100     |ok        |
|f1    |elmt 2 |2       |40 |60          |100     |ok        |
|f1    |elmt 3 |3       |10 |70          |100     |ok        |
|f1    |elmt 4 |4       |50 |120         |100     |ko        |
|f1    |elmt 5 |5       |40 |110         |100     |ko        |
|f1    |elmt 6 |6       |10 |80          |100     |ok        |
|f1    |elmt 7 |7       |20 |100         |100     |ok        |
|f1    |elmt 8 |8       |10 |110         |100     |ko        |
+------+-------+--------+---+------------+--------+----------+
```

Please do drop unnecessary columns from the output